# Tax outputting 0

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that calculates the single or joint tax on the user's income. But whenever I run this program the tax comes back as 0. Any reason why? I cut out the joint tax part to not make it too lengthy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char name[20];
    int filingStatus;
    float salary, rate, tax; 

    printf("Enter name of tax filer:\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Enter your filing status: 1 for Single Taxable or 2 for Married Taxable: \n");
    scanf("%d", &filingStatus);

    if (filingStatus == 1){

        printf("Enter your annual income \n");
        scanf("%lf", &salary);

        if(salary == 0 && salary >= 9325)
            tax = salary*10/100;

        else if(salary == 9326 && salary <= 37950)
            tax = 932.5 + salary*15/100;

        else if(salary == 37951 && salary <= 91900)
            tax = 5226.25 + salary*25/100;

        else if(salary == 91902 && salary <= 191650)
            tax = 18713.75 + salary*28/100;

        else if(salary == 191651 && salary <= 416700)
            tax = 46643.71 + salary*33/100;

        else if(salary == 416701 && salary <= 418400)
            tax = 120910.25 + salary*35/100;

        else if(salary >= 418401)
            tax = 121505.25 + salary*39.6/100;

        printf("The tax for %s is: %f \n", name, tax);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and check your conditions, salary cannot be 0 and 9325 at the same time

Comment: In your `scanf()`, the `%lf` token refers to a `double` not a `float`. Strongly recommend turning on all the compiler warnings you can, it may catch this.

Comment: Formulas like `10/100` will always calculate `0`, because that's an operation between integers and output truncated integer results. That's why the tax is always 0.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with this code, both fatal.

@IlyaBursov has pointed out that the test conditions are wrong:

> if(salary == 0 && salary >= 9325)

There is no circumstance that this test will ever be true; likewise with all the others save for the last. Surely you mean `>` or `>=` instead of `==`.

But the `scanf()` using the token `%lf` is attempting to read a `double` (often 64-bit) instead of the actual 32-bit `float` variables provided. This will produce crazy numerical errors.

Many compilers support higher levels of warnings that will point out this second error, the mismatch between the `%lf` and the pointer associated with it; always enable these when you can.

Example:

```
$ gcc -W -Wall test.c
test.c:20:9: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%lf", &salary);
```

**EDIT**
Also change `scanf("%s", &name);` to `scanf("%s", name);`

Comment: There are two bits of guaranteed UB in OP code: you pointed out one, and @CooperPierce pointed out the other. Mismatched `scanf()` directives and attempting to access uninitialized values both lead to undefined behavior (not just "crazy numerical errors"). There are serious vulnerabilities, too. The input is fragile, but robust input is a can of worms in C; yet one simple and important first step would be to specify a maximum width for `%s` in the call to `scanf()`. This step should _always_ be taken. Turning on warnings is good advice ;)

Comment: I don't think either one are undefined behaviors: aren't both just outright bugs?

Comment: Certainly they are bugs, but it is [UB to use a conversion specifier that does not match its argument.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) Unless I misremember, it is also UB to attempt to access an uninitialized variable (by attempting to print it, for example). I'll have to look a bit harder to find a reference for that one though....

Comment: Here is what I was thinking of (from Annex J.2 of the Standard which lists causes of undefined behavior): ["The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2p1)

Comment: Ok, I think the `scanf` thing goes way beyond that: the code is not referencing memory that's not been initialized, but it's attempting to *store* an 8 byte double into a 4 byte float, and this corrupts memory.  My C language-lawyer days are sadly long in my rear view mirror, but this looks to me like it's well beyond UB.

Comment: Well, my language-lawyering chops are a bit rusty at the moment too;) The `scanf()` thing is called out as UB in the Standard, basically for the reason that you state. The uninitialized UB happens when none of the `if` statement bodies are executed (and given state of OP logic, this is most likely), and `tax` remains uninitialized, after which OP code attempts to print it. In reality, this UB is probably just printing out garbage values; but it is UB, so watch out for monkeys....

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm talking about `scanf("%lf", &salary);` in the face of `float salary`.

Answer (score 1):

All of your conditionals check that it's equal to the lower bound. In the vast majority of cases, none of your if statements are being entered and `tax` will be uninitialized. When you read it to print, you're running into undefined behaviour; it just so happens the memory you got was zeroed.